# Simple DC motor error

Tags: dc-motor, coil

I had tried to make a simple homemade DC motor using 8V DC, Cu coil and a permanent magnet. But it doesn't rotate. Here are the things I did:

1. I made a coil with 6-7 turns using Copper wire.
2. Support is given to coil,through which I had given the supply.
3. And, a permanent magnet is placed under the coil.

The result is that, it is not rotating.
What should I do?

Here is the picture:

[image]

Comment: Insulated copper wire? Have you stripped the insulation at the ends where it's supposed to make contact? Is there current flowing at all? Note that you don't appear to have a commutator so it will give you half a turn at most and then stop.

Comment: Un-insulated copper wire? Are all the turns shorted together? Current will not flow in the loops, if it can just go straight through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That picture is not clear and leaves a bunch of questions.  However, in no case would you expect that setup to continuously rotate just by applying a voltage between the two wires.  Some issues:

The windings appear to be bare copper wire, which would mean they are all shorted together.  The current has to flow around a loop to make a significant magnetic field.  If they are all shorted, then half the current will flow straight to the other side of the loop along the top half-loop, and the other half the current along the bottom half-loop.  There will be no net current going around, and no net magnetic field produced by the loop itself.

Even if this is enamel-coated wire properly connected at the ends and the current flows around the loop, it still won't make the loop spin.  The current will cause a net magnetic field to be formed so that one face of the loop is magnetic N and the other S.  If this field is strong enough, the loop will flip around as needed so that its N aligns with the permanent magnet's S, and vice versa.

To get #2 to work would require a fairly strong magnetic field with this setup.  The magnetic field of the bar magnet looks like it would be fairly weak as far away as the loop is.  Even if all else is right, it would probably take a number of Amps just to see the loop twitch a bit if it is aligned just right.  One way to address this is to use a lot more turns of wire to make the loop.  The magnetic field strength is proportional to the number of turns times the current.

Even if all of the above are right, at best the loop will only flip around once to orient itself opposite of the magnet.  To cause continuous rotation, the current thru the loop needs to be flipped as the loop turns.  Positive current will make the loop want to orient itself one way, and negative current 180° opposite.  To keep the loop rotating, you have to keep flipping the current.  In motor lingo, this is called *commutating*.  Just as the loop gets to where it wants to be for the current going thru it, you have to reverse the current so that it wants to be in the opposite orientation.

This particular type of motor (assuming all the above have been addressed) has no torque twice per cycle, which is when the loop is exactly aligned with the magnet.  That is OK once the motor gets going because inertia will carry it over the dead spots.  However, it can be a problem to get going initially.  At first, you want to apply a steady current and just see the loop try to align itself with the magnetic field.  Therefore start it out so that the plane of the loop is horizontal.